Correct way to sanitize and secure file_get_contents('php://input')
Lets say you have a front end app sending reqiests to a php backend.
On the front end:
fetch("/", {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({
      "data": myData,
    })
  })

On the backend:
$body = file_get_contents('php://input');
$columns = json_decode($body, true);
if (!is_array($columns)) {
  return json_encode("Invalid message body. " . $body);
}

What security considerations do I need to give to accessing file_get_contents('php://input')?
Is columns safe to use or do I need to call some function like sanitizeArray($columns), if so does php have a function like sanitizeArray.

The answer to that depends entirely on what you're intending to do with the data once the PHP script has received it. You can't protect against a threat if there's no threat identified. And we can't identify potential threats until we understand the use case. Just reading the data into a PHP variable is not, by itself, a problem. You ask if it's "safe" to use the data...the only meaningful response to that is "safe against what?".

That depends heavily on how you're using it.  Security isn't a blanket that you pull over your code, it involves understanding what operations you are performing and how those operations could potentially be exploited.

Possible operations are 1. sending this information to another api, 2. storing it in a database in a prepared statement and 3. sending some it back to the frontend possibly modified. I have read there could be a problem with json_encode if the data is large. I mostly use htmlspecialchars() around individual strings.

@aboyce: The security of those operations occurs where those operations occur, not in the code shown.  For example, database interactions should be secured against SQL injection.  Or when sending data to the front-end one should be aware of that data is being rendered to the page and ensure no XSS attacks can occur if users are ever shown data that originated from other users.  Etc.

sending this information to another api...aside from URL-encoding the data if the data is sent as a URL parameter, there's nothing really to do for this use case. It's the responsibility of the receiving API to then do anything necessary to the data depending on what that API then does with it in turn - which of course you cannot know the specifics of.

I have read there could be a problem with json_encode if the data is large...yes, possibly - although you didn't say what problem you mean, or where you read it. But either way "large data" has nothing to do with security.

For point 2 read How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?. Parameterised queries and prepared statements are all you need. That's done when you're actually building the SQL query, of course.

For point 3 read How to prevent XSS with HTML/PHP?. But since in the code you've shown you're JSON-encoding the data, it's not this code's responsibility to HTML-encode it as well - you don't know if the client will use this data in a HTML document or not. It's up to the receiving client-side code to HTML encode it if and when it decides to insert that data into a HTML document.

See also When to use htmlspecialchars() function?

You might use JSON Schema to validate that your input matches expected.

@AlexHowansky that's validation though, not threat protection. Useful, but doesn't seem to be what the OP is getting at here.
